# Geometry(complex number geometry)

Tags: geometry, complex-numbers

Convex polygon $ABCDEF$, $\angle B+\angle D+\angle F=2\pi$ and $\frac{AB}{BC}\cdot \frac{CD}{DE}\cdot \frac{EF}{FA}=1$. Prove that $\frac{BC}{CA}\cdot \frac{AE}{EF}\cdot \frac{FD}{DB}=1$.

My thoughts. Let $z_1=\frac{C-B}{A-B},z_2=\frac{E-D}{C-D},z_3=\frac{A-F}{E-F}$. Then $|z_1|\cdot |z_2|\cdot |z_3|=|z_{1}z_{2}z_{3}|=1$. And Arg $(z_{1}z_{2}z_{3})=2\pi \rightarrow z_{1}z_{2}z_{3}$ is real $\rightarrow z_{1}z_{2}z_{3}=1$.

I suppose this is something, but has little connection with what we need to prove.

Comment: Help me fix the $\LaTex$ as well thanks.

Comment: People don't know what you mean so they might not be able to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let point P to satisfy that $\angle FEA=\angle DEP,\angle EFA=\angle EDP$

Then $\triangle FEA\sim\triangle DEP,\frac{FA}{EF}=\frac{DP}{DE}①,\frac{EF}{ED}=\frac{EA}{EP}②$

According to the given conditions, $\angle ABC=\angle PDC,\frac{AB}{BC}=\frac{DE\cdot FA}{CD\cdot EF}=\frac{DP}{CP}③$

Then we have $\triangle ABC\sim\triangle PDC,\angle BCA=\angle DCP,\frac{CB}{CD}=\frac{CA}{CP}$

Because $\angle FED=\angle AEP$ and ②,$\triangle FED=\triangle AEP$.

Similarly,$\triangle BCD=\triangle ACP$.

Therefore,$\frac{FD}{EF}=\frac{PA}{AE},\frac{BC}{DB}=\frac{CA}{PA}$.Multiply them.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but would my half-done method work?